# Where does React put the continuous build files when using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app, firebase-tools

I'm using `create-react-app`. When I run `npm start` (`react-scripts start`) it continuously builds the changes for me and does it magic. But what is the output folder for that? I know when I build it manually where the files go.

I want to use firebase emulator to serve the current version (the continuous build) of my react all but I don't understand where's the output folder or how to achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this package https://github.com/Nargonath/cra-build-watch

Install it and add the script to your package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "cra-build-watch"
  }
}
```

and run it

`npm run watch`

more info here

https://ibraheem.ca/writings/cra-write-to-disk-in-dev/

and if you go to the react repo [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1070) linked in the article you would find more workarounds

Comment: Not gonna work with the latest  create-react-app version.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**

run `npm run build`, not `npm run start`

**More Detail**

`react-scripts start` runs webpack-dev-server internally. As a default setting, webpack-dev-server serves bundled files from memory and does not write files in directory.
If you want to write files with webpack-dev-sever, you could set [writeToDisk](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#writetodisk) option to true in your dev server configuration.

However, I dont think this is what you want to serve on firebase emulator. Webpack-dev-server does not build optimal app for production, and you also need to use [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to customize dev server configuration in cra template.

What you want to do is `npm run build` to run `react-scripts build`, which builds optimized production app in `/build` directory.

Comment: when you run `build` though, that only creates the files, but doesn't serve them, correct? So like if I'm trying to run a debugger against the `build` in a local dev environment, how might I do that?